# jessie: wake-on-lan -> ok; stretch: wake-on-lan -> broken

Tags: debian, networking, wake-on-lan

I upgraded a headless machine (with openmediavault) from jessie to stretch and after that wake-on-lan stopped working.

I ran down the following checks:

```
>ethtool eth0
-------------------
Supports Wake-on: g
Wake-on: g

>cat /proc/acpi/wakeup
-------------------------------------------
MMAC      S5    *enabled   pci:0000:00:14.0

>cat /etc/default/halt
---------------------
NETDOWN=no
```

- If the machine is up, MagicPackets are received (`nc -ul -p 9`)
- I also installed a *systemd* `wol@eth0.service` with `ethtool -s eth0 wol g` but it didn't do any good

**Q** What do I need to do to get the wake-on-lan back to work?

Comment: hint: are you using NetworkManager?

Comment: @A.B I installed NetworkManager but it isn't showing any connections.

Comment: So it isn't handling eth0? Ok. Else that would have been because NM now handles wake-on-lan and might be disabling it at suspend.

Comment: @A.B I made NetworkManager handle eth0, activated wol in NW but the machine is still not waking up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an OS issue at all, because the wake-up should happen from **S5** (= power-off). Therefore, only the BIOS settings are of relevance. Since the BIOS settings have been working properly for quite a while I conclude there is a hardware-problem.

*Note1* power-on is even instable using the power-button (I double-checked if the switch is defect, which it is not) so it has to be a hardware problem on the motherboard.