# wol: MagicPacket received; machine not waking up

Tags: debian, networking, wake-on-lan

As a follow up to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/518551/352601).

I've confirmed and double-checked

- that the MagicPacket is not filtered
- that the ethernet-card in the machine is powered after shutdown
- that the MagicPacket is received by the ethernet-card - it's flashing, when the MagicPacket arrives

but still the machine is not waking up.

**Q1** What kind of diagnostics can I apply to find out why the machine is not waking up?

**Q2** If the machine is up and running, is there a way to verify that MagicPackets are handled correctly?

Comment: Why is this question talking about a router?  wol packets are not routable

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro All devices are in the same subnet and I've checked with wireshark that the MagicPackets don't get filtered.